# Why do different parts of a spring with mass stretch by different amounts?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, spring

If a massed spring is kept horizontal why should different parts stretch by different amounts?

Suppose a one end is fixed, and the other is free
with a velocity $v$ (uniform velocity)

Suppose in $t$ seconds the free end moves a distance $x $, should the other elements move a distance $x$ along with it?

Also I have seen some stack exchange answers (of similar questions)already but I couldn’t understand them

Can anyone provide a mathematical proof also ?

Comment: Can u elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, That reasoning was wrong due to some confusion . Should not stretch by same amount as I have Just tested myself with small spring that distance between two consecutive elements in spring is constant(means they stretch by same amount)

Comment: But that isn’t true

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315675/kinetic-energy-of-a-massive-spring

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429002/why-does-different-part-of-a-spring-having-mass-expand-proportional-to-their-dis

Comment: Please can u look at them